# EditText lagging with time - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, dynamiclayout

I create app with SpannableString (BackgroundColorSpan, ForegroundColorSpan and StyleSpan). First time EditText work fine, but after 10-15 minutes, the EditText starts to freeze. I use profiler to see why input slow down (photo below)[image: I think that reflow method slow down input]

```
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="11dp"
                    android:paddingRight="70dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="90dp"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLength="999999"
                    android:maxLines="999999"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

ScrollView inside fragment. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should decrease the `android:maxLength` and `android:maxLines` attributes in the xml file. These are very large values and can cause significant lag. Also, if this does not work alone, you should share your Java/Kotlin file as the problem may lie there.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and my solution was to delete:
android:textAllCaps="true"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35408532)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).